# Problem while creating a window in C++ with GLFW 3.3.8 | Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, glfw, visual-c++-2019

i just installed glfw and i was testing the little example project for creating a window, and it just dosn't work, when i create the window, it exits the programm with a "-1" cuz the window is not created, what can i do?
Edit: I fixed it alone :) i just change the compiler to x86 and change a bit the code xd

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize GLFW Library */
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout<<"ERROR: While initializing GLFW!"<<std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    auto* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout<<"ERROR: While creating Window Object!"<<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Initialize GLEW Library */
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s\n", 
        glewGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"Using GLEW %s\n", 
    glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    //TODO: Create and compile shaders here (vertex and frament shaders)
    // and finally draw something with moder OpenGL!

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: _"Edit: I fixed it alone :)"_ Glad to hear you solved it. The SO concept would suggest to create an Answer to your own question telling the details to help others with a similar problem

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add [SOLVED] or [FIXED} to your post title or edit a solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize glfw before creating a window

Call `glfwInit()` before `glfwCreateWindow`

Comment: i figure it out my self, but this is a great help, thanks a lot Light7734 :)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you get the same error, please, change it to x86 in your compiler options, and then, dont initialize the window before de "glfwInit()" or else it will not work